# Plot lines according to "season" based on years and week number given

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have a dataframe with 4 columns. This includes week_no (week of the year), date (the Friday date for that week), year, sales.

I want to plot a line graph showing sales for the winter period by week. The winter period runs from week 50 - week 4. Each winter season should it’s own line and colour.

### Sample dataframe code

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
week_no = c("50","51","52","1","2","3","4","50","51","52","1","2","3","4"),
date = c("2018-12-14", "2018-12-21", "2018-12-28", "2019-01-04", "2019-01-11", "2019-01-18", "2019-01-25", "2019-12-13", "2019-12-20", "2019-12-27", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-10", "2020-01-17", "2020-01-24"), 
         year = c("2018", "2018", "2018", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020"),
sales = c(546,873,532,424,235,321,531,865,869,458,234,654,345,984))
```

### Sample dataframe

| week_no | date | year | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 2018-12-14 | 2018 | 546 |
| 51 | 2018-12-21 | 2018 | 873 |
| 52 | 2018-12-28 | 2018 | 532 |
| 1 | 2019-01-04 | 2019 | 424 |
| 2 | 2019-01-11 | 2019 | 235 |
| 3 | 2019-01-18 | 2019 | 321 |
| 4 | 2019-01-25 | 2019 | 531 |
| 50 | 2019-12-13 | 2019 | 865 |
| 51 | 2019-12-20 | 2019 | 869 |
| 52 | 2019-12-27 | 2019 | 458 |
| 1 | 2020-01-03 | 2020 | 234 |
| 2 | 2020-01-10 | 2020 | 654 |
| 3 | 2020-01-17 | 2020 | 345 |
| 4 | 2020-01-24 | 2020 | 984 |

I’ve tried the below code and it gives a result close to what I need other than the but the years don’t match up correct and the week order is continuous running 1-52.

I desired the x-axis to be ordered as 50,51,52,1,2,3 and each line to show data similarly by date order rather than year.

### Code

```r
winter_line_plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = week_no, y = sales)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = year))
```

I tried using the dates for x-axis but my result showed one continuous line rather than separate colour/lines by the different winter seasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add year as an aesthetic. Keep week discrete, and add scale limits. In order to get the season, your idea in the comment to create a grouping variable for each season is certainly the most straight forward.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  week_no = c("50","51","52","1","2","3","4","50","51","52","1","2","3","4"),
  date = c("2018-12-14", "2018-12-21", "2018-12-28", "2018-01-04", "2018-01-11", "2018-01-18", "2018-01-25", "2019-12-13", "2019-12-20", "2019-12-27", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-10", "2020-01-17", "2020-01-24"), 
  year = c("2018", "2018", "2018", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020"),
  sales = c(546,873,532,424,235,321,531,865,869,458,234,654,345,984))

##  if your data is indeed very regular and contains always one and no more than one row per week,
## then you can easily create the groups with rep
## (make sure the data frame is sorted by year and week)
df %>% 
  arrange(year, week_no) %>%
  mutate(season = rep(c("winter_1819"," winter_1920"), each = 7)) %>%
ggplot() +
  ## week is discrete, so you need to specify group
  geom_line(aes(week_no, sales, color = season, group = season)) +
  ## set axis breaks
  scale_x_discrete(limits = as.character(c(50:52, 1:4) ))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for (both) responses @tjebo. This revised answer is much closer to what I’m trying to get. 
Only, I aim to have only two lines on the plot. One for each winter season running from week 50 to week 4. I have similar plots for the other seasons but because the winter season splits across the year I’m having difficulty.

Comment: Ok, so I think one option is to create a season column (I.e. winter_1819, winter_1920), then group by that column. That may be the only way for me to force from year to season. The x scaling function is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Alwayslearning ah, I see. yes, your approach seems the most straight forward.

Comment: @Alwayslearning have amended my answer

Comment: Thank you! The set is entirely regular. I was trying to think of some logic to apply from the data but this is a much simpler solution. Awesome @tjebo. I’ll do that. Thank you.